# What is the good strategy to maintain Maven transitive dependency satisfied

Tags: maven, nexus, transitive-dependency

I recently encountered a difficulty to find back a transitively dependent Maven artifact when building our product, which triggered me to think what is the correct strategy to deal with the situation.

In my product building CI, I need to use a plugin called Maven-Unix-Plugin, which is visible to us. This plugin transitively depends on function-java, which is not visible to us.

We have a Nexus repo, which proxy to the Maven repo. So, in the ideal situation, we don't need to store either maven-unix-plugin or functional-java.

However, I found the expected version of maven-unix-plugin still exists in Maven repository, but its dependent version of functional-java disappeared! More ironically, for all versions of maven-unix-plugin, whose dependent version of functional-java disappeared! In short, the maven-unix-plugin is not usable anymore!

In simple, this sounds an integrity problem of Maven repository. However, my major thinking is how we can avoid this on our side? Now, I managed to find back the old versioned functional-java and put it in our Nexus. However, first of first, it is impossible for us to figure out all of the transitive dependents and put all of them in our Nexus. The ideal picture of Maven is we should NOT be required to do that!

Of course, if we continuously build and maintain our system (and keep updating the dependency version ideally), we should have not faced this problem. However, we are a very small team to maintain a long list of huge legacy systems. The last build for this product is actually 2 years ago!

Any brilliant insights what is good strategies for this kind of headaches to happen in the future?

Comment: Can you give the exact coordinates of those artifacts?

Comment: Yes, the plugin we are using is org.codehaus.mojo:unix-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3, and by transitive dependency, it finally depends on org.functionaljava:fj:jar:2.16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, MavenCentral very rarely removes artifacts, and only if absolutely necessary. So this problem is likely not to hit you again.

If you want to make sure that this problem will not come again, make sure that you backup the storage of your Nexus repo. All artifacts that are drawn from MavenCentral through your Nexus will be stored in your Nexus storage. So even if MavenCentral is completely wiped out tomorrow, they will still exist in your Nexus.